# Windows 10 Secure Storage

Tags: windows, security, storage

In Windows 10, is there a secure storage mechanism analogous to the Android TrustZone?

Where the data is encrypted and stored in a location separate from regular user file space?

I'm looking to store data from an application that doesn't need to be accessed by any other user or application, and I don't really want to just encrypt it and store it on the disk.

Any thoughts?

Comment: https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/10/13/create-more-secure-apps-with-less-effort-10-by-10/ "By default, UWP apps are isolated in their own container, so their data won’t be accessible by other UWP apps."

Comment: That certainly is a possibility. However, what I currently have is written as a Windows Service, and not a Windows app. 

Is there a method for this that doesn't involve UWP?

Comment: If you're a service, then ACL the files so only the service account can access it. That way, normal users cannot access it. Other applications will need to run under the service account in order to access the file, but so what? If an attacker can configure a service, then they have administrator privileges and can already access anything they want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Windows being an open platform (unlike non-rooted Android - I am talking about the user point of view now) there's no simple way to store anything on the disk (or elsewhere for this matter) and have it protected from user's access. The user is essentially the owner of everything in his PC and on its disk.

The best you can do is use [CryptProtectData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380261%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) / CryptUnprotectData WinAPI functions to "bind" the data to the user account. These APIs don't store the data, but just encrypt it with the key, derived from the user credentials. You then can store this encrypted data in user's profile directory.

Comment: I thought that might be the case.
Thanks!

Comment: do you think there's any downside of storing this encrypted blob in the HKCU part of the registry?

Comment: @PeterWeyzen Microsoft recommends against storing larger amounts of binary data in the registry. If your amount of data is under 2KB, you can store it in the registry. But in general, polluting the registry with data causes the registry to become bloated and fragmented, which affects daily operations.